# Finding out the time when an answer was accepted

Tags: support, answers, timestamps

Is there any way to find out the time *when* an answer was accepted?

In many cases, the exact time of an event can be found by hovering things with the mouse and waiting for a tooltip. But this does not work for the "Accepted answer"-checkmark. The only way seems to be to skim through the reputation changes of the answerer, but this only works well for recent actions...

(Of course, this information is not "important" in a broad sense - it's mainly a matter of curiosity: Sometimes answers are accepted a few seconds after being posted. Sometimes answers are accepted weeks or months later...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, the actual time of the accept is shown in the tooltip, but only *after* a certain amount of time.

> [image: Accept mark with tooltip]

As I'm sure you've noticed, the question timestamps change at a point to show the actual date the question (or answer) was posted. The tooltip for the accept checkmark is the same. It does not get *as* detailed (no seconds/milliseconds) as you could get with a post's timestamp, but it should be enough for any purposes you need.

If you need (or want) to see this information before this time, want to see the *exact* time with seconds and milliseconds included, or you want to see if the accept has changed, then [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy)'s [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293992/2607247) about the timeline of a post is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can look a [the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/293991/timeline) to see when it was accepted.

Comment: "Timeline" was the keyword that I was missing here, obviously (and it opens the door to a world of discussions...: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/248000 )