# Shouldn't there be a time limit when the OP can't unaccept answer (lock)?

Tags: feature-request, unaccepted-answer

I had answered a question on Stack Overflow a few days ago. According to [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156897/when-is-it-okay-not-okay-to-unaccept-an-answer), it's good to unaccept the answer(s) if...

> 1. The OP has accepted before applying it instantly.
> 2. The answer is no longer valid (outdated) and may be a bad impression for future visitors.
> 3. A better answer is given that may lead for betterment.

But the OP of a question suddenly revoked the answer acceptance for no reason:

[image: Answer Unacceptance for No Reason]

I answered the question and got it accepted on **4th July 2020** but found it retracted on **14th July 2020** and I guarantee the answer is still valid and correct to be working.

From my opinion, there should a time limit programmed similar to Vote Up (which can't be retracted after a few mins.)

**Notes to the visitors:**

1. I may link the question when necessary by moderator(s) or staff(s). I didn't do it so to keep the privacy of the Original Poster.
2. I've no problem from the answer unacceptance, but the reason was nothing. Not even any other answer got accepted either.

Any information regards it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The comparison with votes being locked is not correct. An answer doesn't become useful or useless when another answer has been posted, but the other answer can be better and deserve the accepted tick more than the old answer.

Comment: @Tom not even any other answer got accepted either.

Comment: Have you asked OP why they unaccepted your answer, if there is an issue with the post?

Comment: it is part of SO life to have no upvotes, no accepted answers and a lot of downvotes.

Comment: *"but the reason was nothing"* - The reason is likely that the OP thought your answer helped them find a solution, but then turned out it didn't. That is not unfair, that is simply how it goes. They may hope someone else comes along and answers if there is no accepted answer. That can happen at anytime, really.

Answer (score 9):

> From my opinion, there should a time limit programmed similar to Vote Up (which can't be retracted after a few mins.)

Let's remember what the [accept mark](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) means:

> ... accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

and from that same page:

> Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well.

You are not entitled to receive an accept vote, nor is it contractual that an OP can't change their mind, nor that they have to accept a factual correct answer.

Your proposal tries to lock-in a choice that by definition is subject to change. Over time things can change, your own knowledge, experience, you name it. That makes that your view on what answer helped you most changes as well. Locking in that vote makes that OP's might be reluctant to accept an answer because your feature request expects them to predict what the future will bring them so they can be sure your answer is for now and ever the best solution to their problem.

It is suggested in the comments that you can pester the OP by asking them to explain why they unaccepted your answer. I strongly suggest you don't do that. Let's not bully an OP that uses a feature of the site as intended. Demanding explanation is compelling them in (not) accepting an answer and the help center is clear: They don't have to.

Unaccept votes are not public so I can't run stats on it but I expect it to be a relative low number.
I don't think this is a well thought out feature and I advice therefor to not implement it.

Just to be clear. I've had unaccepts (94) as well. Not after two weeks, I give you that. [This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8662086/578411) was accepted on 2012-01-09 at 15:29:28 and unaccepted on 2019-05-09 at 00:39:25. So that is 6 to 8 years later. The answer is obviously controversial as it also saw 2 un-upvotes over its lifetime.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. The answer you link to in the footnote has never been unaccepted.

Comment: @CodyGray Huh? I've found that answer in my reputation history as unaccept event. Does an unaccept event there mean something different then I think it means? I don't have 94 questions so it definitely are not events where I unaccepted an answer on my own question. IIRC an unaccept means that the accept vote is removed from the votes table. So the system basically pretends that accept never happened, at least that is what I understood from a chat with Adam a year back or so. That would explain why it is not visible in the post timeline. If we're really curious we need a dev to confirm.

Comment: I was pretty sure that unaccept events were logged in the post history and would be visible in the timeline. I'm 99.9% sure I've seen them there before. An exception to that might be if the account that asked the question is nuked by a moderator, but that clearly didn't happen here.

Comment: @CodyGray I need to dig more into this. I checked on https://stackoverflow.com/reputation but I can't find the event I based my finding on. I've used the Stack API to get a full reputation audit. That is where I got the event and the post from. I'm about to post a question on MSE to get clarification / confirmation how I should interpret that specific event I got from the SE API.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Maybe it's not tracked after all. I just saw your rep history has a -15 unaccept event for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62229038), but that doesn't have any accept/unaccept history in the timeline view, either. Maybe I'm just misremembering that being in the timeline? It really *should* be there, as repeated accepts and unaccepts have been used as a deliberate annoyance tactic  before, so it's something a mod would want to see. And [this answer from Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293992) confirms they were. I wonder their now being omitted is a bug?

Comment: @CodyGray that answer you linked to was accepted on 2020-06-06 10:26:04 and unaccepted on 2020-06-11 17:38:29. That is what I get from calling the Stack API [Reputation full history](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/full-reputation-history) for my own account.